# Firebase authWithCustomToken throwing an error instead of calling callback?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following the [example in the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithcustomtoken.html):

```
ref.authWithCustomToken(authToken, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Authentication Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

If I pass an invalid token to authWithCustomToken (e.g. authToken is undefined) , it throws an Error, rather than passing an error code to the callback. In other words, neither `console.log` is executed, but this error is thrown:

`First argument must be a valid credential (a string).`

Wrapping it in `try catch` solves the problem easily enough, but I didn't see any mention in the docs. Is it the intended behaviour?

In my use-case the token is passed through a url, so an undefined parameter is a possible error condition.

Comment: What is the error that is being thrown?

Comment: @Rob `First argument must be a valid credential (a string).`

Comment: Show some code.. How are we supposed to see what your code looks like and help you if you provide nothing?

Comment: This is probably related to using the wrong Firebase version. Hard to say without any code to repro.

Answer (score 0):

**From firebase-debug.js:**

```
if (!goog.isString(cred)) {
   throw new Error(fb.util.validation.errorPrefix(fnName, argumentNumber, optional) + "must be a valid credential (a string).");
}
```

**What probably happened:**
You passed a non-string value as `authToken` so the error not happened in the Firebase (server) side, it happened in the client side (your side) so it will be not reported on the callback function but as Javascript exception in your code.

**Possible workaround (I don't know why, but if you want)**
If you want to pass a variable as `authToken` and it could not be a string, and you still want to get the "Wrong credentials" error, instead of type validation, then you need to force string conversion using:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
var numberAuthToken = 212312312312312; // number
var stringAuthToken = String(numberAuthToken);
ref.authWithCustomToken(stringAuthToken, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Authentication Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

But it not makes sense for me. :)